# Redirect apache urls with special characters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need this redirection with mod_rewrite, but I don't have any success.

The url is `http://www.domain.com/descargar catálogo`

I thought this would work:

```
RewriteRule ^descargar%20catálogo$  /url/whatever.php [NC,NE]
```

Any solution for this. I have tried with NE and without, etc...

This gives me internal error:

```
RewriteRule ^descargar catálogo$  /url/whatever.php [NC,NE]
```

Other things I tried but didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^descargar%20cat%C3%A1logo /url/whatever.php
RewriteRule ^descargar\ cat%C3%A1logo /url/whatever.php
```

Comment: try escaping the space (`^descargar\ catálogo$`) or adding quotes around the pattern (`"^descargar catálogo$"`).

Answer (score 0):

URLs cannot contain non-ASCII characters. Escaping the character to represent the actual way the URL is transmitted should do it:

```
cat%C3%A1logo
```

Comment: yes, this should be the way, but in this case there is something which is not working, finally I used the notfound page to redirect because it was impossible, it is not the best solution, but something better than nothing.